# Migrating DB With Encrpytion

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-sql-database

Recently I was informed that Azure SQL V12 now supports
databases that use encryption. I have tried all methods documented here,
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-migrate-ssms/

When attempting to migrate a database I get these kind of errors:
[dbo].[someitem] cannot be deployed as the script body is encrypted

Here is a recent response from an Azure AMA,
https://www.reddit.com/r/AZURE/comments/3o1ea9/ama_azure_app_service_team_109/cvu7xco

what am I doing wrong to get this feature working? As I believe I have performed all the steps as documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure SQL Database V12 supports two types of encryption:

- Transparent Data Encryption as documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn948096.aspx.
- Cell Level Encryption: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms179331.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlsecurity/archive/2015/05/12/recommendations-for-using-cell-level-encryption-in-azure-sql-database.aspx

Which of these are you trying to use?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, at quick glance, mostly stored procedures and views. I believe that similar to the results from the SQL that 'AppService' stated in the AMA.

Comment: The "WITH ENCRYPTION" option can not be migrated using .dacpac or .bacpac formats. It obfuscates procedures and views with a key local to the machine.

If you can decrypt the procedures and views, you can upload them yourself by recreating them on Azure SQL DB v12 databases using CREATE PROCEDURE ... WITH ENCRYPTION (and views). But the migration wizards and tools will not decrypt them for you.

Comment: Is that ever going to change? currently for example we are able to backup a database on 1 machine, and restore it on others and this works despite the local key. I am no expert on the matter, but intentionally decrypting even with good end goals in mind, sounds like a path I personally would not want to go down. I personally feel that a official MS tool to migrate databases to Azure is required.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to migrate the database between 2 different Azure SQL DB servers or between an on premise SQL Server and Azure SQL DB?

Between 2 Azure SQL DB servers, you can do a true backup restore via CREATE DATABASE ... AS COPY OF... syntax (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn268335.aspx). This works because the key is in the database backup.

Between SQL Server and Azure SQL DB, there is no term plan to support moving of encrypted procedures or views.

If you could elaborate why you are encrypting procedures and views, that would help us understand the problems you are trying to solve. Many of the scenarios we've encountered in the past where customers desired procedure and view encryption with SQL Server don't apply to Azure SQL Database, but we're always learning of new challenges people have protecting their databases.

Comment: Hi Jack, we do integration between systems. 1 system in particular which is a ERP program, which uses MS SQL as its data store. The company is an international company, either way their system makes use of stored procedures and views to perform various parts of its functionality, I am talking about a few hundred database objects. They of course encrypt as part of their IP protection. We in turn are trying to create a path where we can potentially migrate customers to Azure. 99% of our customers have existing databases.

Comment: There is also a vast eco-system surrounding the company and product in question, therefore there companies specialising in writing very specific stored procedures and views for companies that make use of the system. Those companies also encrypt their database objects in various scenarios again to protect their IP.

Comment: There is a big drive for a lot of companies to migrate to cloud, from our part we would like to make Azure an option, while VM's can solve the problem partially, Azure SQL in our opinion is the best way to go, where it possible of course. From personal experience I have witnessed many companies using encryption in SQL to protect their intellectual property I would further like to add, that asking the developing companies to drop their encryption and all the companies operating in the eco system to do the same, is simply not an option. It is after all encrypted for a reason.

Comment: We don't offer today uploading of backup files to the cloud, which would enable the scenario you describe.

Comment: If you had control of the application, you could use CLR Obscfucation with SQLCLR procedures and functions as a work around.

Alternatively, you can use SQL Server in an Azure VM which does support .bak file restores.